# How stitch image with cuda？

Tags: opencv, cuda, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

A stitching with CUDA did not work.

OpenCV4.5.1, OpenCV_Contribute4.5.1, CUDA10.2

OpenCV-reference said: "If you have cuda device cv::Stitcher can be configured to offload certain operations to GPU. If you prefer this configuration set try_use_gpu to true." link :
[enter link description here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html)

But there isn't "try_use_gpu" in the sample code.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: OpenCV-reference said: "If you have cuda device cv::Stitcher can be configured to offload certain operations to GPU. If you prefer this configuration set try_use_gpu to true."But there isn't "try_use_gpu" in the sample code. how can i use try_use_gpu in cv::Stitcher.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're following this tutorial, after you have the code compiled, run the executable `./cpp-example-stitching` with the flag `try_use_gpu`, example:

```
./cpp-example-stitching --try_use_gpu true ...
```